# Como acceder a un elemento de un objeto en angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular, angular5

Me encuentro tratando de recorrer lo siguiente

```
 heros: any =[
    { 
      id: 200, 
      name: "Iron man" , 
      poderes: [ 
        {
          name: 'fuerza' , 
          nivel: 200, 
          description: [
            { 
              trabaja: 'DC', 
              jefe: [
                { name: 'Tor', edad: 25  }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },


    { 
      id: 201, 
      name: "Hulk" , 
      poderes: [ {name: 'maldad' , nivel: 500 , 
        description: [{ trabaja: 'Marvel', 
          jefe: [{ name: 'Cap', edad: 105  }] 
        }]
      }]  
    }
  ]
```

Desde el componente lo hago de este otro modo

```
  <table>
  <tr>
     <th>Nombre</th>
     <th>Poder</th>
     <th>Trabaja</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let h of heros">
    <td>{{h.name}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let a of h.poderes">
        {{a.name}}
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let b of a.poderes.description">
        {{b.trabaja}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

No tengo problema en mostrar el nombre del heroe y su poder, pero cuando quiero acceder a el nombre de donde trabaja me muestra el siguiente error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'poderes' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te has liado con la estructura de tu objeto (y yo también, dicho sea de paso): Déjame que te muestre...

```
<tr *ngFor="let h of heros">
  <td>{{h.name}}</td>
  <td *ngFor="let a of h.poderes">
      {{a.name}}
  </td>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero ahora viene el fallo:

```
  <td *ngFor="let b of a.poderes.description">
    ...
```

El `ngFor` de antes, que crea etiquetas `<td>` recorriendo los poderes, **no anida a este otro**, por lo que `a` ya no existe.

Y no puedes anidarlo tal cual porque no puedes crear etiquetas `<td>` dentro de otras, tendrás que ver cómo quieres representar una lista de listas en tu tabla (¿una lista `<ul>` dentro de un `<td>`, quizá?):

```
<tr *ngFor="let h of heros">
<td>{{h.name}}</td>
<td *ngFor="let a of h.poderes">
    {{a.name}}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let b of a.poderes.description">
      {{b.trabaja}}
    </li>
  <ul>
</td>
```

Comment: me sigue apareciendo este error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined ya hice la sustitución de mi código por tu respuesta @Pablo Lozano

Comment: pero como puedes notar ambos tienen poderes y una descripción que indica donde trabajan, comprendo la lógica que me explcias en tu respuesta sin embargo a pesar de tener datos que mostrar me dice que es undefined pero ahora solo para la parte de donde trabajan, el poder de cada uno ya me lo muestra

Comment: Ya he visto el fallo, he editado mi respuesta

Comment: Me ayudaría mucho ya que es mi primera vez usando angular, con un ejemplo con una lista como la que me recomiendas por favor

Comment: Hecho, te dejo los estilos a ti